# BFS, wanting to find longest path between nodes, taking way too long time

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I know there are other, similiar threads about this, my friend Wertyle and I are working together with this bfs-project to find the longest path between two nodes. What we have is a text-file with 3 letter words, only 3 letter words. I also have a Word (node) and queue-class. The code is currently running, but this is an assignment for school, it's supposed to take less than 1 minute to run the code, our code is approximately taking 2-3 minutes, so it's way too slow.

My code is looking like this:

```
def way2(mangd,start):         
    queue=Queue()
    queue.enqueue(Word(start))
    visited=set()                       
    while not queue.isempty():
        s=queue.get()
        if s.ordet not in visited:
            visited.add(s.ordet)
            barn=findchildren(mangd,s.ordet)
            for elem in barn:
                if elem not in visited:
                    b=Word(elem)
                    b.fldr=s
                    queue.put(b)
    return s

def printpath2(start):
    ordet=way2(setlista(),start)
    path=[]
    p=ordet
    while p is not None:
        path.append(p.ordet)
        p=p.fldr
    path.reverse()
    print(path)
    return len(path)


def ordpar(lista):
    s=lista
    a=[]
    a.append(7)
    for elem in s:
        if a[0]<printpath2(elem):
            a.pop(0)
            a.append(printpath2(elem))
    print(a)

def findchildren(mangd,parent): 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

The way2 and printpath2 functions, is taking like half a second to run, (it returns the longest way between a given word to any arbitrary word). Since my text-file contains about 700 words, well, you do the math. I'm suspecting that my way2-method is far too slow, but I dont know how to speed it up. The Findchildren-method is a method which creats all the "children" for a ward, for example, children to "fan" would be "fin","fat","fbn" etc...

As I said, we did post something similiar to this question, I tried to make something out of the answer we got, but unfortunately I think we posted too little code, because I suspect our issue is in the way2 method. Any help is appreciated at this point, thanks in advance!

Comment: post the code of ` findchildren`

Comment: updated with findchildren

Comment: you're not using `set()` but `list()` in `findchildren()`. search performance loss if there are a lot of items.

Comment: Did change that, its still taking too long time, I do have a plan I think, because it seems like a word and its children got the same time to a given word, so if I remove all the children to that word, Ill speed things up

Comment: It feels like I have to decimate the number of words in my original set, but not sure of how I can possibly do this without removing a possible longest word path...

Comment: Is the 1-minute limit given with python language imposed? If not have you tried running it using `pypy` ? It kinds of speeds things up by 200% sometimes.

Comment: As a "clue" we got that it might be a good idea to save the children as a datastructure, I was thinking, maybe you can give my node class another paramteter, like self.children=[] and save the children like that for each word, but I'm unsure how to implement this...

Comment: It looks like this topic died, but my next attempt to make this work is to generate all children immediately, put them in a dictionary, and use them for later, could that work?